# Trying to write a photoshop script to read csv variables

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe, extendscript, photoshop-script

I need corrections on this Photoshop script.

I can open the CSV file but it can't swap out the images on the layers with the images (I used the path) on the CSV file.

It can be achieved without script by using Photoshop variables, but I want to swap out lots of files and can't go back and forth clicking and repeating the task.

```js
// Open the CSV file and parse its content ...
var csvFile = File.openDialog("Select CSV file", "*.csv");
csvFile.open("r");
var csvContent = csvFile.read();
csvFile.close();
var csvData = csvContent.split("\n");

// Loop through the CSV data and replace images on each layer in Photoshop
for (var i = 1; i < csvData.length; i++) {
  var rowData = csvData[i].split(",");
  
  // Open the image file
  var imageFile = new File(rowData[0]);
  var docRef = app.open(imageFile);
  
  // Loop through each layer and replace the image
  for (var j = 1; j <= docRef.layers.length; j++) {
    var layer = docRef.layers[j - 1];
    
    // Check if the layer is a image layer
    if (layer.kind == LayerKind.NORMAL && layer.bounds.toString() != "[0,0,0,0]") {
      
      // Replace the image layer with the new image file
      var imageFilePath = rowData[j];
      var newLayer = docRef.artLayers.add();
      newLayer.move(layer, ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);
      newLayer.name = layer.name;`your text`
      newLayer.kind = LayerKind.NORMAL;
      var imageFileRef = new File(imageFilePath);
      app.activeDocument.activeLayer = newLayer;
      app.load(new File(imageFilePath));
      docRef.selection.selectAll();
      docRef.selection.copy();
      docRef.selection.deselect();
      app.activeDocument.paste();
      layer.remove();
    }
  }

  // Save the modified image file
  var saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  saveOptions.quality = 12;
  var newFilePath = rowData[0].replace(".jpg", "_modified.jpg");
  docRef.saveAs(new File(newFilePath), saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
  docRef.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}

alert("Done!");
```

Comment: `newLayer.name = layer.name;\`your text\`` is gonna throw an error for a start

Comment: It's not clear what the code is supposed to do. Please show your csv data and screenshots: what you have and what you're trying to get.